# Vim: Using <Plug> in a menu definition?

Tags: vim

In my vimrc I have the following mapping:

```
map <leader>ddd <plug>test
```

`<plug>test` is defined in a external vim file in the plugin directory and works as expected.  The problem is when I want to use the mapping in a menu item.  For example, in a custom menu.vim I have the following defined:

```
an 10.631 &File.Test1   <leader>ddd
an 10.632 &File.Test2   :normal <leader>ddd<cr>
an 10.633 &File.Test3   :normal <plug>test<cr>
an 10.634 &File.Test4   <plug>test
```

Only *Test2* works but I would expect the other three to work as well.  Is there something that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t truncate command when you write them: `an` means `anoremenu`. You need `amenu`. If you didn’t truncate commands it would be much easier to guess.